# Button Placement (Add with one field set, enable disable button when more than one)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to ensure only a plus button is showing to add a duplicate field set if theres only one, but add the remove button once a duplicate is created, I have an idea on how to do this by assigning a number value to each duplicate field set created but I cant seem to get it to work, any advice or pointed in the right direction would be great.

Below is the code at this current moment which will replicate the field set once the button is clicked:

```
       $('body').on("click ", '.glyphicon-plus-sign', function() {
        console.log("here ");
        prevInput = $(this);
        count = $(prevInput).attr('data-count=')||0;
        countIncremented = count++;
        br = '<br/><br/>';                  
        $($(this).parent()).clone().insertAfter($(this).parent());
```

I know I need to assign a value to each field set in such a manner as this:

```
newNum  = new Number(num + 1),      
        newElem = $('#entry' + num).clone().attr('id', 'entry' + newNum);
```

But cant get it to work or refactor it to get it to work for my own application.

JSFiddle Link:[Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/PeSa8/23/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always use an if statement:

```
if ($('legend').length < n) { // n being whatever your base number of legends should be
 $('.glyphicon-minus-sign').css({ visibility: 'hidden'});
} else {
 $('.glyphicon-minus-sign').css({ visibility: 'visible'})
}
```

Remember, jQuery selectors return an array of elements matching the selector.

Comment: Thats Brilliant, should it be a separate function in the same way the hover functionality is handled, or? Silly silly question I know.

Comment: I would have it set as hidden to begin with in your css, and then have this if statement nested in your click event. Hope that helps!